# how to display fitXY scaletype using Matrix

Tags: android

im using https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView to show pan zoom functionality in my app.

I would like to impose fitxy behaviour in the initial display of the image. The current settings scales it well the image's width but doesn't display well the height of the image. often you can see a black portion on the top and bottom of the imageview.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use Matrix.setRectToRect http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRectToRect(android.graphics.RectF, android.graphics.RectF, android.graphics.Matrix.ScaleToFit) with stf == FILL